# Zurb Foundation 3 - how to remove dependency on modular-scale Ruby gem

Tags: rubygems, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I'm trying to remove the dependency to the modular-scale ruby gem from my foundation v3 project.

I've successfully pulled the Foundation sass files and the Compass sass files into my project, but I can't figure out how to get modular-scale into sass, so that I don't have to have the ruby gem installed.

I pulled the sassy-math modular-scale.scss file into my project.

Then, I had to back-fill it's depdencies by adding:

```
@import "math";
@import "../common/ratios";

@function power($base, $exponent) {
  @return exponent($base, $exponent);
}

@function golden-ratio($value, $increment) {
  @return modular-scale($value, $increment, $golden)
}
@function golden() {
  @return 1/2 + sqrt(5) / 2;
}    

// Defaults
$ratio: golden_ratio() !default;
```

But then, I'm getting the error:

```
Line 20 of sass/foundation/functions/_modular-scale.scss: 
        Function golden-ratio is missing argument $value.
```

If I change the //Defaults to this:

```
// Defaults
$ratio: golden() !default;
```

I then get this error:

```
Line 165 of sass/foundation/functions/_modular-scale.scss: 
      Undefined operation: "1.61803 times sort_list(14px 44px)".
```

I'm now stuck.  How do I get around this?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: `golden()` isn't a variable, it is a function.  Show the code that's calling this.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the modular-scale or sassy-math extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Many modular-scale functions were written in Ruby to increase performance and it is impossible to get this version of modular-scale working with pure Sass and not this supporting Ruby code. You will probably need to install via the gem although there are other more complicated ways of doing it.

2.0 will support a pure Sass install but has a few breaking changes.